# svn: which files will commit - how to ignore them

Tags: svn, svnignore

I've got the following output from `svn status`

```
$ svn status
 M      .
?       tmp
 M      cron
M       cron/alerts.php
M       Impact.php
 M      logs
 M      conf
M       conf/db.ini       <-- Let's talk about this file
M       conf/impact.xml
```

In my local working copy, I've modified the `conf/db.ini` file to connect to my dev DB server. Since these changes are specific to me, I don't want them to go back up to the repository when I commit.

I've done `svn propedit svn:ignore conf` and listed `db.ini`, but when doing an `svn status` I see that file still has an `"M"` in the first column, making me think that it will still be committed. Am I correct here? If so, what do I need to do to avoid committing my local changes *to that file*?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In looking a little further, I've also found that you can [manually create a changelist](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.5/svn.ref.svn.c.changelist.html), and add the files you want to commit to the change list (works well when you change, say 5 files, but only want to commit the changes to 3 of them). When you commit, you simply commit specifying the name of the custom-created changelist, and you're done.

So, in my case. If I wanted to commit ONLY the changes to 'Impact.php' I could do the following:

```
$ svn cl impact-changes Impact.php
$ svn commit --changelist impact-changes -m "My commit message."
```

Answer (score 1):

My guess is that you have added the db.ini file to the repo, else it would have shown a ? next to it and not a M. So, try backing up your db.ini, remove it from the SVN repo and then try svnstatus

Comment: Well, I'm sure that will work. We want there to be a copy of the db.ini file (at least a copy of the production .ini file) in the repo - so we should probably be creating dev-environment db.ini files to handle development, and then NOT including the dev configs in the repo. My copy of the db.ini file is simply the production copy, modified to work on my dev box, rather than a separate copy for my environment.

Comment: The best solution I've found for keeping a pristine version of a file that developers need to modify locally is to mark the file as ignored in the folder where it's used and keep the clean version in a separate folder.  It can be inconvenient for builds, but presumably you're doing those from a script.